# PHPMyAdmin: Many-to-Many relations in MyISAM (without foreign key support)

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, phpmyadmin, innodb, myisam

I've discovered that my host may only support MyISAM and not InnoDB.  Thus, I lack built-in foreign key support.  How would I then implement a many-to-many relationship with three tables in PHPMyAdmin?  The only solution is to enter in the relations manually through MySQL queries, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement it in the same way as you would using Innodb but ensure data integrity in the application layer.   If you have a good data abstraction layer then this should be fairly simple to implement.